# Batch insertion of records in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Is batch insertion of records   possible in cakephp ?

Kindly reply me if possible show me some samples ?

My Query will look like

```
INSERT INTO `job_places` (`id`, `country_code`, `group`, `name`) VALUES
 (1, 'DE', 3, 'Hamburg'),
 (6, 'FFF', 1, 'Frankfurt');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have `saveAll` for things like this http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data

> Used to save (a) multiple individual records for a single model or (b) this record, as well as all associated records
>   For saving multiple records of single model, $data needs to be a
>   numerically indexed array of records like this:

```
Array (

>     [Article] => Array(
>           [0] => Array
>               (
>                             [title] => title 1
>                         )
>           [1] => Array
>               (
>                             [title] => title 2
>                         )
>                 ) )
```

In your example, you'll need to format your data array like:

```
$data = array(
   'Job' => array(
      array('id' => 1, 'country_code' => 'DE', 'group' => 3, 'name' => 'Hamburg'),
      array('id' => 6, 'country_code' => 'FFF', 'group' => 1, 'name' => 'Frankfurt')
   )
);

$this->JobPlace->saveAll($data['Job']);
```

Nothing beats trying when you are learning something, so give that a go and post any problems you are having rather than wait for someone to post the exact code where you can just copy paste.

Comment: Just put the Job model name with $data  $this->JobPlace->saveAll($data['Job']); otherwise it won't work

Comment: One fallback on this method is that cake creates one query per record. In this case it is not significant, but if you try to insert 1000 rows it makes sense

Comment: This is not the answer. It creates query per row, example provided in question is on query for all rows